# cannot "enable debugger" in server explorer for azure vm, visual studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-virtual-machine

What can be the reason I cannot enable debugger for some of my VM's in server explorer?

I try to follow this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines

When I right click on the VM in Visual Studio Server Explorer I do not get the same options as in the tutorial:

[image]

This is the menu I expected to see (from the tutorial):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because that your VMs are ARM VM, not Classic VM.

I did a test in my Lab, and found that  I cannot enable debugger on my ARM VM neither. But I can enable debug on a classic VM. (Pay attention to two different types the icon of VMs)

[image]

**For a classic VM, you can enable debugger on it and then Attach debugger.**

[The official documen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines#debugging-azure-virtual-machines)t doesn't clarify this feature is only for classic VM. But the icon for the screenshots are all for Classic VM.

So, we cannot enable Debugger on a ARM VM from Visual studio. If this feature is very important to you, you can post your idea in [this Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I have some old Classic VM's which work so you are probably right.